# how to calculate the derivative of a discrete Laplacian

Tags: derivatives, optimization, numerical-methods, nonlinear-optimization, finite-differences

This is a problem when I'm doing inversion using Tikhonov regularisation. It can be simplified to (only the regularization part)

$$
f(m) = \sum_{\textrm{all i, j}} (\bigtriangleup m(x_i, y_j))^2
$$

$\bigtriangleup$ is a discrete Laplacian operator using finite-difference method. Because I use the iterative inversion strategy, I need to calculate the derivative of $f(m)$ on $m$.

I have known $m(x_i, y_i)$, how to calculate $\frac{\partial f}{\partial m}(x_i, y_i)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing complicate here.

$$(\Delta m)_{i,j} = \sum_{l,k} c_{l,k} m_{i+l,j+k}$$
where $c$ are the coefficients of [your discrete Laplacian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Laplace_operator#Implementation_in_image_processing)

Note that 
$$\frac{\partial (\Delta m)_{i',j'}}{\partial m_{i,j}} = \sum_{l,k} c_{l,k} \frac{\partial m_{i'+l,j'+k}}{\partial m_{i,j}} = c_{i-i',j-j'} $$

Then $f(m) = \sum_{i,j} (\Delta m)_{i,j}^2$ is a function of $m_{i,j}$ and what you want is $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial m_{i,j}} = \sum_{i',j'} \frac{\partial(\Delta m)^2_{i',j'}}{\partial m_{i,j}} = \sum_{i',j'} 2(\Delta m)_{i',j'}\frac{\partial(\Delta m)_{i',j'}}{\partial m_{i,j}}= \sum_{i',j'} 2(\Delta m)_{i',j'}c_{i-i',j-j'} $$

Comment: Could you explain the second equals sign more in the second equation of your answer? Or give me some keywords or documents so that I can look up it.

Comment: @Aristotle0 What do you not understand here ? The [partial derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative) and why $\frac{\partial m_{1,2}}{\partial m_{1,1}} = 0$ ? Well because $m_{1,2}$ doesn't depend on $m_{1,1}$..

Comment: I know $\frac{\partial x}{\partial y} = 0$ is correct for partial derivative. Is it right when applying derivative on discrete situation. It looks strange. $m_{1, 2}$ is one value and $m_{1, 1}$ is also one value. Is $\frac{\partial m_{1, 2}}{\partial m_{1, 1}}$ valid?

Comment: @Aristotle0 what do you mean with "discrete situation" ? Here $\{m_{i,j}\}_{i = 1 \ldots N,j = 1 \ldots N}$ is just a (finite) set of variables, and $f$ is a function of $n$ variables, in the same way that $g(x,y) = x^2+y^2$ is a function of $2$ variables

Comment: Though I'm still a little confused, I tried a numerical experiment and the result seems good. Thanks a lot.